# Как установить NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Помогите, плз разобраться с установкой. Никогда с NodeJs не сталкивался, с npm тоже.Понимаю, что все написано, но установить так и не получилось.
Что делал? Скачал\установил nodejs актуальную версию. Распаковал архив в папку, куда по умолчанию смотрит cmd.- cmd(npm init). Дальше пробовал npm instal, npm run webpack-devserver - ошибки. Подскажите, пошагово и как надо делать?

-npm install
-cp etc/client-config.json.sample etc/client-config.json (by default connect to production REST API)
-npm run webpack-devserver (wait until build is ready, it will create file "etc/webpack-assets.json")
-npm run nodemon (in another terminal, and wait until build is ready)
-open http://localhost:3001

Comment: пробовал, так а что не получилось?

Comment: `sudo pamac install nodejs`

Comment: Не понял как реализовать второй пункт. Ввожу сразу npm run webpack-devserver - выдает ошибку  missing script...

Comment: что значит второй пункт. Как правильно его реализовать? Ввожу сp etc\client-config.json. sample etc\client-config.json - пишет cp - не является командой npm

Comment: @AlexanderYukal, причем тут "нормальная консоль"?

Comment: @Voprositel согласен, нипричем.

Answer (score 0):

Перейдите на nodejs.org, скачиваете node. Открываете установочник, везде прокликиваете next. Для проверки установился ли nodejs введите в cmd "node -v". Если выдаст версию -значит у вас успешно установился nodejs
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHKXBeG4pnY`